# Laravel paying amount with credit card through device/ machine

Tags: laravel, payment, device

In store when some payment pay thought credit.
there is any solution how to integrated with laravel.
Any reference or any solution how i paying amount with credit card through  device / machine

Comment: Square and use their payment integration

Comment: in laravel payment through card swipe machine.

Comment: Suppose purchase some things in store unfortunately i have no cash payment  then i pay amount through the card swiping machine.